# Issue copying ScriptPath from one user to another

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello I am having an issue copying the ScriptPath from one user to another in PowerShell.

```
$currentUserScriptPath = Get-ADUser -Identity currentuser -Properties ScriptPath | Select ScriptPath
Set-ADUser -Identity newuser -ScriptPath $currentUserScriptPath
```

[UserProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INZz0.png)
This is what I am getting for the Logon script. All I want is the .bat script. I am sure it is something dumb I am missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just get the value from the variable you can change  `$currentUserScriptPath` to:

```
$currentUserScriptPath = (Get-ADUser -Identity currentuser -Properties ScriptPath).scriptpath
```

or

```
$currentUserScriptPath = Get-ADUser -Identity currentuser -Properties ScriptPath  | Select ScriptPath -expandproperty scriptpath
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a test to see if the ScriptPath property for user `currentuser` is empty or not and only set if to user `newuser` is it isn't.

```
$currentUserScriptPath = (Get-ADUser -Identity currentuser -Properties ScriptPath).ScriptPath
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($currentUserScriptPath)) {
    # the currentuser has an empty ScriptPath property.
    # if you want the newuser to also have its scriptPath removed, uncomment the next line
    # Set-ADuser -Identity newuser -Clear scriptPath
}
else {
    Set-ADUser -Identity newuser -ScriptPath $currentUserScriptPath
}
```

Comment: Great Idea! I have added this as well. Thank you for this